# Login - The CSRF token could not be verified - Not able to login into admin

Tags: admin, migration

I have migrated my Craft CMS from Cpanel Apache server to Ngnix server.

Site is loading perfectly fine, whereas the Control Panel area is not working.

It is giving following error message;

> Bad Request: The CSRF token could not be verified

Comment: This might not be a solution but what happens when you turn your csrf validition off, login to the admin panel, clear the cache as well as the session storage and turn it on afterwards?